# UnityGfxDeviceW Crash

Tags: plugins, unity-game-engine, crash

I have a problem testing an app for android with unity, when I run the application on my Phone, the application opened and crash inmediatly after that with this message in the logs:

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x64397000 (code=2), thread 28557 (UnityGfxDeviceW)
```

I suposed that is a problem of video memory, I tested on differents phones and only works perfectly on HUAWEI CE0197, on many others phones crash with that error.

I have some plugins installed:
Prime31 EtceteraAndroid (For use camera and file manager).
AndroidNative (for use facebook).
OnlineMaps de Inifnity Code
NGUI for manage the views

Thanks.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Yes and no, this was many years ago, but the problem was "the memory", I use the profile viewer to improve the app an solve

Answer (score 1):

Check the options in Player Settings ,there may be some options like Minimum API Level not correct and Stripping Level

Comment: Perhaps this could be a comment, as it does not offer a researched answer